# Flash urlrequest relative path in IE

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, internet-explorer

I am making a small flash script for uploading files. I have:

flash/flash.swf

index.html

upload.php

My problem is that when I want to call the urlrequest I do req.url = '../upload.php'. This works for firefox but not for IE (IE 9). 
So firefox seems that needs the relative path of upload.php to flash.swf, while IE seems that need the relative path of upload.php respect index.html.

Is there a cross browser solution to this problem?

Comment: NPAPI and ActiveX may offer differing services in this regard.  Can you not use the fully qualified url?  Flash should be able to get it's root url, and it's fairly simple from there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instruct looking for the upload script from the top directory tree.

So instead of "../upload.php", you must use "**/upload.php**".

By the way I understand it, your file system looks like this:

> **index.html** (The file where you embed the SWF file)
>
> **upload.php**
>
> **yoursubdirectory/youruploader.swf**

This is the reason why you used "../uploader.php" thinking that SWF must
pull the upload script from the outside of its residing folder.

But you don't need to do this.

---

If you're currently working in the localhost and your files resides in a sub-folder like the example below:

**http: //localhost/myuploader/**

Then you'll have to use "**/myuploader/upload.php**".

Otherwise, if they reside in the very root then "**/upload.php**" still does the trick for both FF and IE.